# AngularJS apply select2 on element within modal

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to apply select2 on a select element within a modal.

The modal is defined as a `script ng-template`. This works fine if it's not a modal (or a template).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#typeDescription").select2({
            placeholder: 'Select a type...',
            allowClear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

However I cannot include the above code within

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal">

</script>
```

So the thing is I want to apply select2 on my element on the modal. How can I do that? How can I access the modal element by id and apply select2 on it?

EDIT:

I made some changes:

On the controller I made a function:

```
......
 $scope.select = function() {

    $(document).ready(function ($) {
         $("#typeDescription").select2({
               placeholder: 'Select a type...',
               allowClear: true
         });
    });

 };
```

and then within my template:

at the select filed (see bellow) I did like this: `data-ng-init="select()"`

and actually works, it applies the select2 to my element.

Is this a proper approach? Can I make use of ng-init for this case?

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="currentModal.close();" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field-1">Name</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newType.Name" id="field-1" placeholder="Name">
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field-5">Description</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" data-ng-model="newType.Description" cols="5" id="field-5" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="field-5">Select Type</label>

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <select class="form-control" id="typeDescription" data-ng-model="newType.Type" data-ng-init="select()">
                        <option data-ng-repeat="item in allTypes.Types" value="{{item.Value}}">{{item.Text}}</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-gray btn-single" data-ng-click="currentModal.close();">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-single" data-ng-click="createType(); currentModal.dismiss();">Save</button>

    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: For angular you should use [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you create a directive wrapping the select2 plugin:

```
var lib = angular.module('lib');
lib.directive('mySelect', [function() {
  var link = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.select2({
      placeholder: attrs.placeholder,
      allowClear: attrs.allowClear
    });
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: link
  };
}]);
```

use it like this:

```
<select data-my-select placeholder="'Select a type...'" allowClear="true"></select>
```

This will initialize the select2 when the select control is rendered.